# C++ Class Set, skip first 2 values

Tags: c++, oop

I have a class set up at the top of my program called InventoryVector, this stores all items in the program, product name, price and quantity.

Through the admin section of the program the product name, price and quantity have allready been defined, my question is when the user picks a item to purchse then i need to lower the available quantity of that item.

This is what i have come up with:

```
InventoryVector[i].setInventory(VOID,VOID,test);
```

I need to skip the VOID part and leave these unedited, I only want to replace the 3rd variable in the class with (test)

Simply put, my question is just, how to i skip the first 2, leave them untouched and only edit the 3rd. 
Thankyou

EDIT : 
Here is the function storing the information :

```
void setInventory(string x, double y, int z) {
    sProductName = x;
    dProductPrice = y;
    iQuantity = z;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is answerable without a crystal ball to tell me what `InventoryVector` is.

Comment: That is the name of the function, all i want to do is skip the first 2 values of the set function, I will add the function handeling this to the question incase  thanks

Comment: well then pass it and dont change it :D

Comment: @krazaq Added, thanks

Comment: InventoryVector[i].setInventory( , ,test);

Comment: The class your working with does have any other access modifiers to change a single thing?

Comment: Ive tried this, guessing its incorrect

Comment: `InventoryVector[i].setInventory(InventoryVector[i].getName(), InventoryVector[i].getPrice(), test);` ? But a quantitySetter seems more appropriate.

Comment: It would be a nice way to use `std::ignore`, I think.

Comment: Thankyou Jarod, Working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your class does not have a single property setter and you can't change it, you probably have to use something like

```
auto& ref = InventoryVector[i]; // for brevity
ref.setInventory(ref.getProductName(), ref.getProductprice(), test);
```

Answer (score 0):

When I understood it correctly then this should solve your problem:

```
void setInventory(int z) {
    iQuantity = z;
}
```

The other members remain untouched.